# Visual Studio 2013.3 publish to azure website via web deploy validate connection fails with no error code

Tags: visual-studio, azure, publish

In Visual Studio 2013.3 I have created a test .Net 4.5  C# MVC 5 project to run in an Azure Website. I created a new Azure a/c and logged into it in VS. When I try and publish the project (running VS as Administator) the Validate Connection fails with no error code. I have re-downloaded the Publish settings from Azure to make sure I have the correct publish settings. The message I get is:
(2014-10-27 11:04:13) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
The server experienced an issue processing the request. Contact the server administrator for more information.

When I try and publish the project anyway I get the following message:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4270,5):
>   Error : Web deployment task failed. ((2014-10-27 11:06:25) An error
>   occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)
>
> (2014-10-27 11:06:25) An error occurred when the request was processed
>   on the remote computer. The server experienced an issue processing the
>   request. Contact the server administrator for more information.
>   Publish failed to deploy.

I have installed the latest Azure SDK for Visual Studio 2013 2.4.1 via MS Web Plaform Installer 5.
The online Azure management pages shows the default website running. I'm running Windows 8.1.

One thing I have noticed is that if I change the sitename in the Publish settings I get:

> Could not connect to the remote computer [...] The Remote name could
>   not be resolved.

Also when I try to ping the remote url i.e. [sitename].scm.azurewebsites.net:443 it times out, however, I can access it via a browser.

[UPDATE]
By Changing the output to verbose I get this message:

```
(2014-10-27 12:28:01) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
The server experienced an issue processing the request. Contact the server administrator for more information.
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.GetHttpResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.PerformHeadRequestHelper(Boolean getVersionInfo, Version& maximumSupportedVersion, Version& minimumSupportedVersion)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider..ctor(DeploymentProviderContext providerContext, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, String serverVersion)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObjectPrivate(DeploymentProviderContext providerContext, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentObject sourceObject, String serverVersion)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateDestinationObject(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentObject sourceObject, String serverVersion)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , Object , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid4[T0,T1,T2,T3](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.VSMSDeployObject.SyncTo(VSMSDeployObject destObject, Object syncOptions, IVSMSDeployHost _host)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , VSMSDeployObject , VSMSDeployObject , Object , IVSMSDeployHost )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid4[T0,T1,T2,T3](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.BaseMSDeployDriver.InvokeMSdeploySync()
   at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.VSMSDeployDriverInCmd.StartSync()
   at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.BaseMSDeployDriver.SyncThruMSDeploy()
   at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.VSMSDeploy.Execute()
        VSMSDeploy: Publish failed to deploy.
        Done executing task "VSMSDeploy" -- FAILED.
```

Many thanks in advance.
Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with the Windows region setting I was using. Apparently the region I was using wasn't supported by the VS publish system and Microsoft hadn't a fall back setup. I posted the question on an MSDN forum and a Microsoft engineer worked out what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

I ran to a similar problem while trying to publish Azure Mobile Service. Finally I managed to get rid of the problem by using MSDeploy.exe with -verb:delete parameter. I cannot provide you with the exact command line for your case, but in my case I've downloaded .publishsettings file from Azure Management portal and then I've run the following command:

```
set MSDeployPath=C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\
"%MSDeployPath%"\msdeploy.exe -verb:delete -dest:ContentPath=<site name here>,PublishSettings=<path to downloaded .publishsettings file here>,AuthType='Basic'
```

Without .publishsettings file you'd have to deal with detailed parameters: computername, username and password.

After running the above command, I could publish my mobile service from VS.